# Gatling Maven plugin and Maven 3.3.3

Tags: java, maven-3, maven-plugin, gatling

For some reason SLF4J is removed from the classpath when you use Maven 3.3.3. I found some links with some info about it but it's not clear to me how to fix this issue.

- https://github.com/gatling/gatling/issues/2632
- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-5791#add-comment

I tried adding the dependency to the plugin itself like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>io.gatling</groupId>
    <artifactId>gatling-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${gatling-plugin.version}</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.12</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>performance-test-1</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>execute</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                .....
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

But that doesn't seem to work. Does anybody know how to solve this issue?

Comment: The issue is fixed since 2.1.5. Which version do you use? What's your issue exactly?

Comment: I upgraded to 2.1.7 and it seems to work again. Thnx!

Comment: Cool. Filling a full answer instead of just a comment.

Answer (score 1):

This compat issue has been fixed in 2.1.5.
Just upgrade.